# Upgrade from v4 to v5 material-ui, css is broken

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I use custom css for material-ui(newly MUI) project.

I tried using new packages for the version 5 but my older CSS doesn't seem to be working.

I wonder if there is a trick that I can use to fix them.

For example I was using: Accordion, AccordionSummary, AppBar, Tabs, Tab and so on...

```
import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionDetails,
    AccordionSummary,
    AppBar,
    Avatar,
    Box,
    Chip,
    Grid,
    Tab,
    Tabs,
    Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
...
<StylesProvider injectFirst>
    <Accordion className="contract-card-wrapper">
                <AccordionSummary
                    className="contract-accordion-summary"
                    expandIcon={<img src={ExpandMoreIcon} alt="expand-more-icon" />}
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                >
                </AccordionSummary>
               ...
</StylesProvider>
```

Note: I use ... for some code blocks. And in the css

```
.MuiAccordionDetails-root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
...
```

But it doesn't seem working at the moment.
How can I override them again? What is the proper way to override styles of the material-ui components? Especially with version 5.

Comment: https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/

Comment: Can you put your code on codesandbox?

Comment: I'm having a lot of errors when I try to put my code onto codesandbox.